# using a typedef statement inside and outside of a class declaration block

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I'm designing a class which has a vector object of pointers of the same class' objects.

For example:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class X
{
private:
   vector<X*> _neighbors;
};
```

I want to use a `typedef` statement to shorten my work, but I want to use it outside of the class declaration as well, for example in another class. Where should I write the `typedef` statement? before the class declaration? after it?

Comment: `typedef` of *what* ? Also, please don't `use namespace std;`, especiallty in headers.

Comment: @Quentin, `typedef` for `vector<*x>`, And why shouldn't I use `using namespace std`?

Comment: Because you dump the whole honking content of the standard namespace in the global namespace, name collisions and all. And if you do that in a header, you do that upon the *user's* code.

Comment: 'using namespace std' in a header file forces it on everyone that transitively includes your header. The reason not to force it is the exact reason the 'std::' namespace was added - prevent naming collisions. In your implementation files (cpp/cxx/whatever) feel free to use your own conventions.

Comment: @Quentin, ok, so I won't use it. It's weird/funny because the default hello world uses it just like I did. I've picked it up from there I think

Comment: @ZachiShtain this dreaded line is indeed found in an astounding quantity of "tutorials" and "courses". You'd think it stands for "Scholarly Transmitted Disease".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could **declare** the class before **defining** it:

```
#include <vector>

class X ;

typedef std::vector <X*> AX ;

class X {
    AX _neighbors ;
} ;
```

Or as a shortcut (thanks to @PaulRoub):

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector <class X *> AX ;

class X {
    AX _neighbors ;
} ;
```

Comment: Since there's only a pointer reference involved, can't you just skip the `class X` forward declaration and say `typedef std::vector <class X*> AX ;`? e.g.: https://ideone.com/3pwQzi

Comment: Use a namespace too if you can :)

Comment: @PaulRoub AFAIK I cannot do that since the compiler won't know what `X` is when declaring `typedef std::vector <X*> AX ;`. It fails at least with g++ 4.7.2: "'X' was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Working fine for me with g++ 4.1.2, and in the linked example. Note that you left out the `class` keyword inside your typedef.

Comment: @PaulRoub You're right, it works if I add the `class` keyword.

Comment: @PaulRoub I did not think it was possible to declare a class in the context of a typedef (or a function), thanks for pointing out that feature!

Comment: Forward declarations only. I'm not sure it's an improvement, but it's definitely another style choice.